# Auto reproduce video list from specific directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, html5-video

Is there a way to auto play all videos from specific directory using `video` tag when one video ends the next start and take all the videos from the directory using `JavaScript/JQuery`.

For example, I need show the page whith one video player `<video></video>` this video player need to reproduce automatically all the videos from specific directory continually, the idea is put in all directory all the videos to reproduce so is necesary to dinamically detect that videos and create that list, after all videos were play it search again for the videos in the directory and start again with the play list.

It is possible do this just with `html5/JavaScript`?

Comment: It is possible, but not standard functionality. You'll have to build your own system and logic for it to work.

Comment: It's possible with Javascript on server side using NodeJs for example... Otherwise without a given array of filenames you can't ! You need a server-side script to list the directory files using php or nodejs...

Comment: I solve the problem about name list of the files but how can I play all the video list one by one in sequence?